# Go to new screen after using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using `MFMailComposeViewController` to let the user send an email within the app, and stay in the app. When the've finished using `MFMailComposeViewController`, I want them to go to a new screen, not the one that they just came from.

Below is the code I have for handling whether or not should close.

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //put segue here (???)
}
```

What I'm not sure how to do at all is transition to another screen if the case case `MFMailComposeResultSent:` is reached. Does anyone have any ideas on a way to implement this?

**EDIT** Below is what I changed based on @TonyMkenu's answer (I know it's not correct yet though).

```
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            BOOL mailSent =true;
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    if (mailSent == true)
    {
        NSLog(@"Mail was sent, going to next screen." );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your interface make a Property:

```
@property BOOL mailSent;
```

in the `MFMailComposeResultSent` case set the Bool to Yes/true

```
case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            self.mailSent=true;
            break;
        }
```

now, just check the Bool.. (don't use `if (bool == true)` .. just `if (bool)` or `if (!bool)`

```
 // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        if (self.mailSent) {
            self.mailSent=false; // now, "reset" the Bool
            NSLog(@"Mail was sent, going to next screen." );
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to navigate to another screen when mail composer transition is done.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    //Your segue, or another transition here. 
}];
```

Comment: The only reason I was hoping not to do that was because I wanted to present the user with an acknowledgment that their email had been sent, rather then have them go straight back to the screen that allowed them to send the email. 

Is there another approach to this I've not thought of yet?

Comment: @narner you can "put" a BOOL (for example) mailSent=true in MFMailComposeResultSent case, and check this BOOL in the above completion; if true.. segue to your desired ViewController

Comment: @TonyMkenu Hi Tony, thank you for your comment. That idea makes sense. I edited my question based on my understanding of your answer, but I know I'm doing something wrong. Would you mind taking a quick look? Thank you!